# How can I stop Attiribute error 'NoneType' object using if statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

When I run it, I get an x ​​error after a certain time. I know I got this error because it's at the end of the page. How do I stop the program without receiving this error?

I tried

```
if newsContents == "NoneType":
        break
```

or

```
if newsContents == " ":
        break
```

My code is:

```
while i < 30:
    r = requests.get("blabla" + str(i))
    source = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")
    i=i+1
    newsContents = source.find("div", attrs={"class": "figCaption"})
    print(newsContents.text)
    print("#"*10)
```

print(newsContents.text)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: `if not newsContents: break`

Answer (score 0):

Try this if statement

```
if newsContents is None:
        break
```